# Trying to use `pdfgrep` program from within my command

Tags: interactive

I want to be asked what string `%s` I want [0] pdfgrep to search for? While `M-x pdfgrep mysearchString` works, I'm somehow missing something on wrapping it up as sole function?

```
(require 'pdfgrep)
(pdfgrep-mode)
(defun myPdfSearch ()
  (interactive)
  (pdfgrep -H -n -i -r %s /home/pdf/))

Symbol’s value as variable is void: -H

[0] https://github.com/jeremy-compostella/pdfgrep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pdfgrep` *function* that you call from lisp is not the `pdfgrep` *program* that you invoke from the command line, so you have to format the arguments as the function expects. Try:

```
(defun myPdfSearch (s)
  (interactive "sSearch string: ")
  (pdfgrep (format "pdfgrep -H -n -i -r -e \"%s\" /home/pdf/*.pdf" s)))
)
```

This is the equivalent of the command line invocation

```
pdfgrep -H -n -i -r -e "<string>" /home/pdf/*.pdf
```

It's a good idea to use `-e` to signal that the next argument is the expression to search for and to quote that expression to protect spaces and metacharacters from tripping up the shell invocation.

AFAICT, `pdfgrep` requires *files* as arguments, not directories, so you have to use the glob pattern to pick up all the PDF files in the specified directory.

I also had to load the `pdfgrep` library and evaluate `(pdfgrep-mode)` before I could use the above.